# Trying to Save Outlook Email in a Folder

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook-2010

I have a WinForms app that at the click of a button automatically produces an Outlook mail as follows:

```
public static void CreateOutlookEmail(string pFileName, string pCaseFolder, string pEmail, string pSubject, string pMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);                
            mailItem.Subject = pSubject;
            mailItem.To = pEmail;
            mailItem.Body = pMessage;
            mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
            mailItem.Display(false);
            string fileDetails = pCaseFolder + "\\" + pFileName + @".eml";
            mailItem.SaveAs(fileDetails);
        }
        catch (Exception eX)
        {
            throw new Exception("cDocument: Error occurred trying to Create an Outlook Email"
                                + Environment.NewLine + eX.Message);
        }
    }
```

The code succesfully opens a new Outlook email, and populates it with the details sent into the method e.g. email address, subject and the body of the message.

Also when I locate the folder (sent in as a paramater) I can see the email document has been saved.

The issue is, that when I open the email from the folder, the email document is totaly blank ii.e. no email address, subject or message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Just use extension ".msg" instead of ".eml". Also the eml format does not exist under Outlook.OlSaveAsType

Comment: Done and now it says I dont have permission to perform that action and will not save the document at all?

Comment: The message is probably open in outlook. Can you check? Also, you can comment the line mailItem.Display(false); I have used your snippet adn am able to save the message, so there should not be a problem.

Comment: The whole point of this code is to create and open a new email, populate it with basic info e.g. address, subject, and then autosave it in a regular windows folder.  So yes, the email will be open at the time when the application attempts to save this.

Comment: Ok. Can you use a temporary file name to open the mail item? Once you are done with the processing, you can save it with the name you prefer. If the saved file is open, you will not be able to write to it the next time, for sure, as it is already open.

Comment: I need to save it immediately once created, rather than relying on the user to remember to save it.

Comment: Can you state the current status? Are you still getting any error?